# Matching a substring of any length and characters using RegEx

Tags: c#, .net, regex, substring

I would like to be able to match and then extract all substrings in the following string using regex in c#:

```
"2012-05-15 00:49:02 192.168.100.10 POST /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync/default.eas User=nikced&DeviceId=ApplDNWGRKZQDTC0&DeviceType=iPhone&Cmd=Ping&Log=V121_Sst8_LdapC0_LdapL0_RpcC31_RpcL50_Hb3540_Erq1_Pk1728465481_S2_ 443 redcloud\nikced 94.234.170.42 Apple-iPhone4C1/902.179 200 0 64 3140491"
```

Since it's a logfile it the regex should be able to handle any line that is of a similar type.

In this case, the preferred output to a collection should be:

```
2012-05-15
00:49:02
192.168.100.10
/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync/default.eas
User=nikced&DeviceId=ApplDNWGRKZQDTC0&DeviceType=iPhone&Cmd=Ping&Log=V121_Sst8_LdapC0_LdapL0_RpcC31_RpcL50_Hb3540_Erq1_Pk1728465481_S2_
443
redcloud\nikced
94.234.170.42
Apple-iPhone4C1/902.179
200
0
64
3140491
```

Appreciate any answer using C#, .net and Regex to extract the above substrings into a collection (MatchCollection preferred). All log lines follows the same format and pattern.

Comment: What's the difficulty in using C# RegEx? Apart from 'can't be bothered to do it myself' ?

Comment: I know there is an answer already but I am intrigued by what you already tried...

Answer (score 3):

Incredibly complex regex incoming:

```
logFile.Split(' ');
```

Comment: KooKiz: Can you explain that to me? Its a bit complicated and I can't quite see how it works... ;-)

Comment: I probably should have included that I need a solution that does NOT use the obvious split on space, sorry about that.

Comment: @NIklas Persson: Then you should specify what your exact requirements/constraints are. The fact that you can't split on plain space might affect any potential regex solutions too.

Comment: I need a solution that can split the string into substrings without using space as delimiter. I have no idea if its possible or not using regex. I can identify a substring that consists of time using \d+\:\d+\:\d+ for example but it's not pretty.

Comment: As LukeH says, we need to understand why splitting on whitespace is forbidden. You say *All log lines follows the same format and pattern*, but presumably whitespace is different in some records? What is the full story please?

Comment: @NIklasPersson *how are your substrings defined,* if not by spaces?  Your sample data shows that the substrings are delimited by spaces, but your objections to the given answers imply that there is some more subtle definition at play.  Before anyone can answer this question, you have to come up with logic to answer the question "what is a substring?"

Comment: @phoog: see the OP's comment to my solution below. He is worried that a `String.Split` will extract a lot of irrelevant data so wants a regex to find only what is required.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you an array that you can iterate through to retrieve all of the "lines" which are separated by a space

```
string[] lines = log.Split(' ');
```

Comment: I can't use the split on ' ', I need to extract the separate fields without that which makes it kinda tricky. Finding Date, time and ip is easy since I can match on the following:\d+\-\d+\-\d+ \d+\:\d+\:\d+ \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a Regex. You can simply use [String.Split Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx), and specify space as separator:

```
  string [] substrings = line.Split(new Char [] {' '});
```

If you need to identify the kind of each part, then you should specify what you need to find, and a regex can be created for it.

Anyway, if you really want to use a Regex, do this:

```
  Regex re = new Regex (@"(?:(?<s>[^ ]+)(?: |$))*");
```

This will give you all the captures in the "s" group, when you call the Match method.

As the OP pointed out in a comment that the separator can be anything appart from a single space, then the possible separators should be included in the `(?: |$)` and the `[^ ]` parts of the expression. I.e. if space as well as tab are possible separators, replace that part with `(?: |\t|$)` and `[^ \t]`. If you need to accept more than one of those characters as separators, add a `+` after the `()` group:

```
  (?:(?<s>[^ \t]+)(?: |\t|$)+)*
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and most obvious way is to use `String.Split`:

```
string[] substrings = result = line->Split( nullptr, StringSplitOptions::RemoveEmptyEntries );
```

But if you insist on a `MatchCollection` then this will do what you want

```
MatchCollection ^ substrings = Regex.Matches(line, "\\S+")
```

Comment: I need to go through tons of logfiles and identify, match and extract the different substrings into fields so that I can find the ones which are actually important. Since the logfiles can consist of massive nonvital and sometimes irregular information I need regex to match the ones that are of interest.

Comment: Aaah! Then you are optimising before you have shown a more straightforward method to be too slow. A regular expression will be slower than a simple `String.Split` and you should start by generating *all* the fields this way and simply ignoring those you don't need.

Comment: Perhaps another possibility is, if the log file has fixed-width fields, you can simply extract substrings at hard-coded positions?

Answer (score 0):

Really, you just need to break this down into the parts.

First, the date. Will it always be in YYYY-MM-DD format? Could it be possible that it will be different based on region/culture settings?

```
(?<LogDate>dddd-dd-dd)
```

Next, you have the time. Same thing:

```
(?<LogTime>dd:dd:dd)
```

Next, I'm assuming this is the web method that was actually called? Not entirely sure, since you haven't really explained how the data is laid out. However, I'm assuming it's either going to be either POST or GET, so that's what we're going to do next...

```
(?<LogMethod>POST|GET)
```

Just do this for every part of the log line you're interested in, and you'll be set.  IE:

```
(?<LogDate>dddd-dd-dd) (?<LogTime>dd:dd:dd) (?<LogMethod>POST|GET)...
```

If you want to anchor to the start/end of the line, be sure to use ^ and $ respectively. When you get the Matches, you can get the values from each group by indexing the Groups property with the named group (such as `match.Groups["LogMethod"].Value`). Good luck!

Comment: This is what I want to achieve but how do I extract/match the following part and the parts after it: /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync/default.eas
User=nikced&DeviceId=ApplDNWGRKZQDTC0&DeviceType=iPhone&Cmd=Ping&Log=V121_Sst8_LdapC0_LdapL0_RpcC31_RpcL50_Hb3540_Erq1_Pk1728465481_S2_

Comment: This solution presumes that there is whitespace where indicated in the sample log record, but we now understand that this may not be the case.

Comment: @NIklas Persson: a simple regex of `\S+` will match that string, but can we assume that it contains no spaces? Please explain the deal with whitespace.